# Create "one time event" based on StateFlow in Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a ViewModel that contains a StateFlow of a class, where some different states are emitted.

Class that emit states:

```kotlin
class SampleClass {
    private val _state: MutableStateFlow<SampleState> =
        MutableStateFlow(SampleState.Idle)

    val state: StateFlow<SampleState> =
        _state.asStateFlow()

    suspend fun doSomething() {
        if (_state.value !is SampleState.Idle) return
        _state.update { SampleState.Started }

        try {
            delay(1000) // simulates a task delay
            _state.update { SampleState.Finished(true, Random.nextInt(10, 100)) }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _state.update { SampleState.Finished(false, 0) }
        } finally {
            _state.update { SampleState.Idle }
        }
    }
}

sealed interface SampleState {
    object Idle : SampleState
    object Started : SampleState
    data class Finished(val success: Boolean, val value: Int) : SampleState
}

fun SampleState.toTextMessage(): String = when (this) {
    SampleState.Idle -> "nothing to do now"
    SampleState.Started -> "started something"
    is SampleState.Finished -> if (this.success) "success" else "failure"
}
```

ViewModel:

```kotlin
class SampleViewModel(
    private val sampleClass: SampleClass
) : ViewModel() {
    val sampleState: StateFlow<SampleState> = sampleClass.state.stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        SampleState.Idle
    )

    fun doSomething() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            sampleClass.doSomething()
        }
    }
}
```

Composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SampleScreen(viewModel: SampleViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val sampleState by viewModel.sampleState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        // not working as expected
        when (val state = sampleState) {
            is SampleState.Finished -> {
                if (state.success) snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                    "Completed with value: ${state.value}"
                )
            }

            else -> {}
        }
    }

    Scaffold(snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) }) { scaffoldPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(scaffoldPadding)
        ) {
            Text(text = sampleState.toTextMessage())

            Button(onClick = viewModel::doSomething) {
                Text(text = "do something")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is, in addition to displaying a message according to the current state of a task, at the end of it (if finished with success) perform another action, such as displaying a snackbar or other thing.

The part of having a message on the screen is working normally but I couldn't perform any action when the state went through `SampleState.Finished`.

I tried to find information about an implementation for this but I couldn't find it. What I saw was about `Channel` and `SharedFlow`, but I couldn't understand how to integrate this into my case. If anyone can guide me... Many thanks!

---

When changed the `LaunchedEffect` key to `sampleState is SampleState.Finished` and added some delay on `finally` block on `SampleClass` I get the result I wanted, but in a way that seems wrong to me, with artificial delay between `SampleState.Finished` and `SampleState.Idle`.

Comment: `key1` needs to be `sampleState`, not `Unit`. By the way, that `finally` block that emits an Idle state after a short delay is quite fragile code. It could cause a Finished state to get skipped since StateFlow is conflated.

Comment: The idea is not to have any delay before switching from `SampleState.Finished` to `SampleState.Idle`. That delay on `finally` block I ended up putting in the example by accident. But then I won't be able to make this work without adding a longer delay?

Comment: It's not trivial since recompositions can happen quickly and cause intermediate States to be dropped without ever being used in the UI. What you're trying to do is like an event system--intermediate values must not be dropped until they are handled by the UI. They have an article about doing that [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events). Basically, your state's class needs a "isHandled" `var` property that doesn't participate in equals/hashcode. Only change it to handled when you're done with the event ("finished" in this case).